# Python Pandas - CSV Import RFC 4180

Tags: python, pandas, csv, rfc4180

I've a short question about the csv module of pandas. Is the format standardized (RFC 4180)? Perhaps based on the Lib/csv.py module? Is this documented (source)?

Comment: _Is the format standardized (RFC 4180)? Perhaps based on the Lib/csv.py module?_ I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: The python csv module (Lib/csv.py) uses the description of the Internet Engineering Task Force (RFC 4180). But i can get no information if pandas csv module uses this description, too.